# Why does sharing page on Facebook does not show the image?

Tags: php, html, facebook, meta

So, I have this article page which sometimes has post with image of 600x315 dimension and are mostly under 100kb.

Following are the meta I use on the article.php site, but when I share a post on Facebook the image **section shows blank**. What is that I am missing on these meta?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $row['keyword']; ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo metadesc($row['description']); ?>">
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $site_path.$url; ?>" />

<!-- for Facebook -->          
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php  echo ucletters($row['title']); echo ' | '; echo $site_name;?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $site_path.'uploads/images/'.$row['image']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $site_path.$url; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo metadesc($row['description']); ?>" />

<!-- for Twitter -->          
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php  echo ucletters($row['title']); echo ' | '; echo $site_name;?>" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo metadesc($row['description']); ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php echo $site_path.'uploads/images/'.$row['image']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Does your $site_path contain full address including "http" ?

Comment: yes site.path is like http://www. mysite .com/

Comment: and it does have http

Comment: @AliSheikhpour you there mate?

Comment: check the website control panel and make sure images are not protected from hot linking. Also do not use space or non-English characters in image urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit 
[Facebook developer debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

to check the issue with your url(s).Read their guidelines and that will surely work.Good luck

Comment: i went through that already tried debug but it keeps telling image size exceeded how could that be when image is under 100kb not even mb.

Comment: Can you provide the image URL?

Comment: the actual or ? well it looks like this http:// www. site. com/uploads/images/1476784488.jpg had to give space else cannot post in comments here

Comment: mate it fixed it was not related to this code but i had .haccess blocking hotlinking :)

Comment: That's great :)